# flutter scrollIntoView

Tags: scroll, dart, flutter

This method appears to be for testing, but I actually need to scroll a widget onto the screen after rebuilding the UI with more widgets.

This exists in the GWT world.

Is there any way to achieve this in Flutter ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Listview Scrolling to widget](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49153087/listview-scrolling-to-widget)

Comment: Also this is a good read if you're interested as it describes a few options and why it isn't possible out of the box: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/12319. The TLDR is that if your widgets are all the same size it's easy but otherwise much more difficult.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [scroll_to_index](https://pub.dev/packages/scroll_to_index) plugin as a workaround. Keep tab on the Widget's index that you'd like to navigate to utilize this package.