# flutter ListView scroll to index not available

Tags: dart, flutter

**What I needed:**

I want to scroll a list by some index, how can i do that.

**What I know:**

`scrollToIndex` should start from n index, but how can we scroll to any index?

Comment: Try [indexed_list_view](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/indexed_list_view).

Comment: check this post I wrote: https://medium.com/@diegoveloper/flutter-lets-know-the-scrollcontroller-and-scrollnotification-652b2685a4ac

Comment: @JeromeEscalante i already checked indexex_list_view but it is infinite list my list is coming from database and size will be dynamic.

Comment: @diegoveloper i also checked your post, but in my case list item size is not fix.

Comment: you can also try this one: https://github.com/quire-io/scroll-to-index

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to scroll to an index by its index number in flutter listview?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57545392/how-to-scroll-to-an-index-by-its-index-number-in-flutter-listview)

Comment: checkout this link https://stackoverflow.com/a/67560929/10700096
thank you.

Answer (score 58, accepted):

Unfortunately, ListView has no built-in approach to a scrollToIndex() function. You’ll have to develop your own way to measure to that element’s offset for `animateTo()` or `jumpTo()`, or you can search through these suggested solutions/plugins or from other posts like [Flutter: Scrolling to a widget in ListView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49153087/flutter-scrolling-to-a-widget-in-listview)

*(the general scrollToIndex issue is discussed at [flutter/issues/12319](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/12319) since 2017, but still with no current plans)*

---

But there is a different kind of ListView that does support scrollToIndex (*as mentioned by Slashbin*):

- **[ScrollablePositionedList](https://pub.dev/documentation/scrollable_positioned_list/latest/scrollable_positioned_list/ScrollablePositionedList-class.html)**

  - dependency: [scrollable_positioned_list](https://pub.dev/packages/scrollable_positioned_list)

You set it up exactly like ListView and works the same, except you now have access to a [ItemScrollController](https://pub.dev/documentation/scrollable_positioned_list/latest/scrollable_positioned_list/ItemScrollController-class.html) that does:

- `jumpTo({index, alignment})`
- `scrollTo({index, alignment, duration, curve})`

Simplified example:

```
ItemScrollController _scrollController = ItemScrollController();

ScrollablePositionedList.builder(
  itemScrollController: _scrollController,
  itemCount: _myList.length,
  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
    return _myList[index];
  },
)

_scrollController.scrollTo(index: 150, duration: Duration(seconds: 1));
```

*(note that this library is developed by Google but not by the core Flutter team.)*

Comment: Fantastic answer. Though I noticed that when `index == item.length - 1`, the scrollController behaves funny. Perhaps it's because I used`BouncingScrollPhysics()`

Comment: The downside of ScrollablePositionedList is that its incompatible with incremental scrolling requires (such as responding to arrow up/down keys), because its API does speak about offsets (even relative offsets).

Comment: But I cannot set controller key for ScrollablePositionedList, it's not good if you want to do something more

Comment: what about a ListView builder inside a streamBuilder. will this work?

Comment: but the scrollable positioned list doest not have scrollcontroller like in listview builder which can be helpful to detect user scroll direction .

Answer (score 12):

`ScrollablePositionedList` can be used for this. 
https://github.com/google/flutter.widgets/tree/master/packages/scrollable_positioned_list

[Pub link - https://pub.dev/packages/scrollable_positioned_list](https://pub.dev/packages/scrollable_positioned_list)

> 

```
final ItemScrollController itemScrollController = ItemScrollController();
final ItemPositionsListener itemPositionListener = ItemPositionsListener.create();
```

> 

```
ScrollablePositionedList.builder(
  itemCount: 500,
  itemBuilder: (context, index) => Text('Item $index'),
  itemScrollController: itemScrollController,
  itemPositionsListener: itemPositionListener,
);
```

> One then can scroll to a particular item with:

```
itemScrollController.scrollTo(
  index: 150,
  duration: Duration(seconds: 2),
  curve: Curves.easeInOutCubic);
```

Answer (score 6):

Use `scroll_to_index` lib, here scroll will be always performed to sixth position as its hardcoded below

```
dependencies:
    scroll_to_index: ^1.0.6
```

**Code Snippet:**

```
class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  final scrollDirection = Axis.vertical;

  AutoScrollController controller;
  List<List<int>> randomList;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    controller = AutoScrollController(
        viewportBoundaryGetter: () =>
            Rect.fromLTRB(0, 0, 0, MediaQuery.of(context).padding.bottom),
        axis: scrollDirection);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: ListView(
        scrollDirection: scrollDirection,
        controller: controller,
        children: <Widget>[
          ...List.generate(20, (index) {
            return AutoScrollTag(
              key: ValueKey(index),
              controller: controller,
              index: index,
              child: Container(
                height: 100,
                color: Colors.red,
                margin: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                child: Center(child: Text('index: $index')),
              ),
              highlightColor: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.1),
            );
          }),
        ],
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: _scrollToIndex,
        tooltip: 'Increment',
        child: Icon(Icons.add),
      ),
    );
  }
  // Scroll listview to the sixth item of list, scrollling is dependent on this number
  Future _scrollToIndex() async {
    await controller.scrollToIndex(6, preferPosition: AutoScrollPosition.begin);
  }
}
```

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: it struggles with very long lists and does not have jumToIndex function

Answer (score 4):

You can use the [flutter_scrollview_observer](https://github.com/LinXunFeng/flutter_scrollview_observer) lib to implement your desired functionality without invasivity

Create and use instance of ScrollController normally.

```dart
ScrollController scrollController = ScrollController();

ListView _buildListView() {
  return ListView.separated(
    controller: scrollController,
    ...
  );
}
```

Create an instance of ListObserverController pass it to ListViewObserver

```dart
ListObserverController observerController = ListObserverController(controller: scrollController);

ListViewObserver(
  controller: observerController,
  child: _buildListView(),
  ...
)
```

Now you can scroll to the specified index position

```dart
// Jump to the specified index position without animation.
observerController.jumpTo(index: 1)

// Jump to the specified index position with animation.
observerController.animateTo(
  index: 1,
  duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 250),
  curve: Curves.ease,
);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your package @LinXunFeng, it works like a charm ;) I'm using it with nb_utils AnimatedListView , and works fine, thanks bro'

Answer (score 2):

It's simple to scroll to preferred index if you know listview item size like:

```
var index = 15;
var widthOfItem =
176; //in dp. width needed for horizontallistView;
var heightOfItem =
200; //in dp. height need for vertical listView;
listViewScrollController.jumpTo(index * widthOfItem.toDouble());
```

or

```
listViewScrollController.animateTo(
index * widthOfItem.toDouble(),
duration: Duration(milliseconds: 500),
curve: Curves.ease);
```

Answer (score 1):

Found a gist and its working gist url is https://gist.github.com/debuggerx01/b8ef756ee02b3eb82ec3702f14ba94e6

this gist is using a package which is calculation rect size. 
https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/rect_getter

Comment: Yes, it works, but looks like FPS in my listview with comments has become very low.. too much operations.

Comment: is it possbile using this solution if  i'm using ListView.builder ?

Answer (score 0):

You can scroll into position by calculating your item position.

```dart
int itemCount = 5; // your items count
ScrollController scrollController = ScrollController();
int index = 2; // your item index to scroll

scrollController.jumpTo(
   scrollController.position.maxScrollExtent/ 
     (itemCount-1) * index
);
```

This will scroll you to some way around item, then you can have the best place for yourself by index some offset