# How to scroll to an index by its index number in flutter listview?

Tags: flutter, flutter-listview

I have a listview . I want to go to a certain widget by it's corresponding index number.

I've tried with ScrollController, but it need offset value to jumpTo the index. But I want to jumpTo a widget by using its index number.

Please, help me to fix it
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Listview Scrolling to widget](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49153087/listview-scrolling-to-widget)

Comment: this also looks similiar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54039684/flutter-listview-scroll-to-index-not-available/54287123

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63620653/10511266 people who looking for solution might help

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Unfortunately, ListView has no built-in approach to a scrollToIndex() function. You’ll have to develop your own way to measure to that element’s offset for `animateTo()` or `jumpTo()`, or you can search through suggested solutions/plugins from other posts such as:

- [flutter ListView scroll to index not available](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54039684/flutter-listview-scroll-to-index-not-available)
- [Flutter: Scrolling to a widget in ListView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49153087/flutter-scrolling-to-a-widget-in-listview)

*(the general scrollToIndex issue is discussed at [flutter/issues/12319](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/12319) since 2017, but still with no current plans)*

---

But there is a different kind of ListView that does support scrollToIndex:

- **[ScrollablePositionedList](https://pub.dev/documentation/flutter_widgets/latest/flutter_widgets/ScrollablePositionedList-class.html)**

  - [scrollable_positioned_list](https://github.com/google/flutter.widgets/tree/master/lib/src/scrollable_positioned_list)
  - dependency: [flutter_widgets](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_widgets)

You set it up exactly like ListView and works the same, except you now have access to a [ItemScrollController](https://pub.dev/documentation/flutter_widgets/latest/flutter_widgets/ItemScrollController-class.html) that does:

- `jumpTo({index, alignment})`
- `scrollTo({index, alignment, duration, curve})`

Simplified example:

```
ItemScrollController _scrollController = ItemScrollController();

ScrollablePositionedList.builder(
  itemScrollController: _scrollController,
  itemCount: _myList.length,
  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
    return _myList[index];
  },
)

_scrollController.scrollTo(index: 150, duration: Duration(seconds: 1));
```

*(note that this library is developed by Google but not by the core Flutter team.)*

Comment: Fantastic answer. Though I noticed that when `index == item.length - 1`, the scrollController behaves funny. Perhaps it's because I'm using `BouncingScrollPhysics()`.

Comment: shrinkWrap isn't there in this plugin