# How to scroll to a specific element in listview and map?

Tags: flutter

I am new flutter developper, I'm working on a Listview to display some elements horizontally and display them at same time on the map.
What I'm looking do it, is the same thing implemented by Google map when we search something like pharmacy:

- display one element on the screen
- when we scroll the current element is marked on the map
- when click on a marker on the map, the associated element from Listview is displayed on the screen

Please do you have any idea how can I do it?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you checked this : https://stackoverflow.com/q/54039684/7666442

Comment: Thanks, but how can display one element on the screen?