# Once a notification has been touched, how will I be able to go to the notifiers scroll postion of the screen?

Tags: flutter, dart, notifications, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have a screen where I am able to see the people I am following. I have them in a list(vertical) of containers, so let's say that I am following 40, then some of them will not be visible, (For example, 10 visible at a time). The containers hold some information about themselves, that they can update whenever they want, and once they do I will get a notification. If person 30 updates their information and when I click on the notification, I want it to automatically scroll down to that position of the screen.

I need some guidance and advice on how to achieve this. I have searched, but could not find anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can use ScrollablePositionedList. However, for reference, you can check [this answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58924800/9661936) since it's already answered.