# Flutter: Jump to specific item by item data in ListView.builder

Tags: flutter, listview, scroll, jump-list

It's possible to jump to specific item by item data in ListView?

```dart
class Test extends StatelessWidget {
  Test({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  final _list = <String>[
    "INFWARS_CH01_EP01",
    "INFWARS_CH01_EP02",
    "INFWARS_CH01_EP03",
    "INFWARS_CH01_EP04",
    "INFWARS_CH01_EP05",
  ];

  void _scrollToItem() {
    final specificItem = "INFWARS_CH01_EP04";
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: ListView.builder(
        itemCount: _list.length,
        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
          final data = _list[index];
          return Text(data);
        },
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: () => _scrollToItem(),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

as you can see, I want to jump to specific item in ListView by specific data `"INFWARS_CH01_EP04"` using `_scrollToItem` function, `not by index or by position`.

So the item ListView for `INFWARS_CH01_EP04` will be in the top (scrolled). For now in the top is `INFWARS_CH01_EP01`.

It's possible to do it?

Comment: I am not sure what actually you want but I think you can do data.contain('INFWARS_CH01_EP04') ? this : or do something else in here

Comment: I want to `jump in` / `scroll to` specific item in the `ListView.builder` by item data (`"INFWARS_CH01_EP04"`)

Comment: I make an update in question, pls take look

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fix it using this package: https://pub.dev/packages/scroll_to_index

So you can scroll / jump to specific item by index / by item data in ListView.

```dart
class Test extends StatelessWidget {
  Test({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
  AutoScrollController _scrollController = AutoScrollController();

  final _list = <String>[
    "INFWARS_CH01_EP01",
    "INFWARS_CH01_EP02",
    "INFWARS_CH01_EP03",
    "INFWARS_CH01_EP04",
  ];

  void _scrollToItem() async {
    final specificItem = "INFWARS_CH01_EP04";
    final index = _list.indexOf(specificItem);
    await _scrollController.scrollToIndex(
      index,
      preferPosition: AutoScrollPosition.begin,
    );
    await _scrollController.highlight(index);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: ListView.builder(
        controller: _scrollController,
        itemCount: _list.length,
        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
          final data = _list[index];
          return AutoScrollTag(
              key: ValueKey(index),
              controller: _scrollController,
              index: index,
              child: Text(data),
          );
        },
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: () => _scrollToItem(),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To scroll to a specific item you can:

1. Find the specific item using the [`indexOf()`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.16.1/dart-core/List/indexOf.html) method:
2. Use the [`scrollable_positioned_list`](https://pub.dev/packages/scrollable_positioned_list/) package to scroll to that item.

Here is a complete working example:

```
class Test extends StatelessWidget {
  Test({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
  ItemScrollController _scrollController = ItemScrollController();

  final _list = <String>[
    "INFWARS_CH01_EP01",
    "INFWARS_CH01_EP02",
    "INFWARS_CH01_EP03",
    "INFWARS_CH01_EP04",
  ];

  void _scrollToItem() {
    final specificItem = "INFWARS_CH01_EP04";
    _scrollController.jumpTo(index: _list.indexOf(specificItem));
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: ScrollablePositionedList.builder(
        itemScrollController: _scrollController,
        itemCount: _list.length,
        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
          final data = _list[index];
          return Text(data);
        },
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: () => _scrollToItem(),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

See also: [flutter ListView scroll to index not available](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58924800/12349734)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I need it using `ListView.builder` not using `ScrollablePositionedList.builder`. It's possible?

Comment: @RRifaFauziKomara See the provided link in my answer. This is the best way to do it. Why do you need it to be a `ListView`? what's the difference?

Comment: Like in my question, no need to `scroll by index or position`, I need it to `scroll by item content (ex: INFWARS_CH01_EP04)`. Because to show a list data I use this package: https://pub.dev/packages/inview_notifier_list

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [flutter_scrollview_observer](https://github.com/LinXunFeng/flutter_scrollview_observer) lib to implement your desired functionality without invasivity

Create and use instance of ScrollController normally.

```dart
ScrollController scrollController = ScrollController();

ListView _buildListView() {
  return ListView.separated(
    controller: scrollController,
    ...
  );
}
```

Create an instance of ListObserverController pass it to ListViewObserver

```dart
ListObserverController observerController = ListObserverController(controller: scrollController);

ListViewObserver(
  controller: observerController,
  child: _buildListView(),
  ...
)
```

Now you can scroll to the specified index position

```dart
// Find the specific item index.
final targetIndex = _list.indexOf(specificItem);

// Jump to the specified index position without animation.
observerController.jumpTo(index: targetIndex)

// Jump to the specified index position with animation.
observerController.animateTo(
  index: targetIndex,
  duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 250),
  curve: Curves.ease,
);
```