# How to create a Flutter horizontal list with images and show data, changing selected item color while allowing only one item to be selected at a time?

Tags: flutter, dart, listview, row

I am new to Flutter and have been trying to create a horizontal list with images where I can display some data. I attempted to use `ListView.builder`, but unfortunately, it doesn't seem to work as expected. I also searched for solutions on Stack Overflow, but none of them resolved my issue.

What I want to achieve is a horizontal list with images like this: [Flutter Horizontal List Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JvSww.png). Additionally, I want to change the color of the selected item to indicate that it's currently selected. However, I need to ensure that only one item can be selected at a time. So, when I select another item, the previously selected item should be deselected.

I would appreciate any help or guidance on how to implement this behavior effectively. Thank you in advance for your assistance!

Comment: Can you include your code-snippet that you;ve tried so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to provide height while using horizontal listView. A great video about [Unbounded height / width | Decoding Flutter](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jckqXR5CrPI)

You can play with this widget.

```dart
class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<MyApp> createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  int? _selectedIndex; // if you want to provide default selection, init here
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Column(
        children: [
          SizedBox(
            height: 30,
          ), //top level space
          SizedBox(
            height: 68, // play with height
            child: ListView.builder(
              itemCount: 33, //number of item you like show
              scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                return Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                  child: InkWell(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12),
                    onTap: () {
                      setState(() {
                        _selectedIndex = index;
                      });
                    },
                    child: Container(
                      alignment: Alignment.center,
                      width: 48,
                      height: 48,
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12),
                        color:
                            _selectedIndex == index ? Colors.blue : Colors.grey,
                      ),
                      child: Text("$index"),
                    ),
                  ),
                );
              },
            ),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Check more about layout on [flutter.dev](https://docs.flutter.dev/development/ui/layout)

Comment: I want to use the icons for moving through the list. how do i do that?

Comment: wrap with row and provide 1st and last child, middle child will be Expanded<ListView>, You can also check [scrollable_positioned_list](https://pub.dev/packages/scrollable_positioned_list) Also check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54039684/10157127)

Comment: let me know if you’ve failed to archive it