# How to scroll chat screen on send message

Tags: flutter, listview, scroll, chat, messaging

I have a chat screen, and I want to send message, on send message the list view should scroll down to the bottom to the last message that it's sent.
please help me

here is the body

```
      body: WillPopScope(
        onWillPop: pressBack,
        child: Container(
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
            children: <Widget>[
              SizedBox(
                height: 0.02 * MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
              ),
              Expanded(
                child: SizedBox(
                  width: 0.9 * MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                  child: ListView.builder(
                    controller: _scrollController,
                    itemCount: messageList.length + 1,
                    itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, index) {
                      return index == 0
                          ? Container()
                          : oneMessage(messageList[index - 1]);
                    },
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              SizedBox(
                height: 0.02 * MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
              ),
              texWriteInBottomBar(),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
```

here we write the message and send it

```
  texWriteInBottomBar() => Container(
        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
        height: 0.08 * MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
        child: Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
          children: <Widget>[
            SizedBox(
              width: 0.04 * MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
            ),
            myTextFormField(),
            SizedBox(
              width: 0.02 * MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
            ),
            GestureDetector(
              onTap: sendMessage,
              child: SizedBox(
                  height: 0.1 * MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
                  width: 0.1 * MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
                  child: Transform(
                    alignment: Alignment.center,
                    transform: (getTranslated(context, 'language')=='ar')?Matrix4.rotationY(math.pi):Matrix4.rotationX(0),
                    child: Image.asset(
                      'assets/images/Chat/send.png',
                      fit: BoxFit.fitHeight,
                    ),
                  )),
            ),
            SizedBox(
              width: 0.02 * MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
            ),
          ],
        ),
      );

  myTextFormField() => Expanded(
        child: SizedBox(
          width: 0.6 * MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
          height: 0.08 * MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
          child: TextFormField(
            controller: _textEditingController,
            onChanged: (text) {
              setState(() {
                messageText = _textEditingController.text;
              });
            },
            onFieldSubmitted: (text) {
              sendMessage();
            },
            textAlign: TextAlign.right,
            decoration: InputDecoration(
              border: decor,
              focusedBorder: decor,
              enabledBorder: decor,
              errorBorder: decor,
              disabledBorder: decor,
              fillColor: Color(0xffF3F3F3),
              filled: true,
              hintText: getTranslated(context, 'Say something'),
              hintStyle: TextStyle(
                color: Color(0xff909090),
                fontFamily: 'Cairo',
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      );
  void sendMessage() async {
    setState(() {
      messageList.add(Message(
          messageText,
          '',
          '${DateTime.now().year} ${DateTime.now().month} ${DateTime.now().day} ',
          '${DateTime.now().hour} : ${DateTime.now().minute}',
          widget.sender));
      _textEditingController.text = '';
    });
    scrollToBottom();
  }
scrollToBottom(){

}
```

as you see the last function is scrollToBottom(){} but it's empty, so what should I write in

Answer (score 1):

See you dont have to implement a seperate function to you know show messages in a down to bottom. You can directly start from the bottom as we do in Instagram or whatsapp you just need to use
`reverse:true` as mentioned bellow and you will achieve that

```
ListView.builder(
                reverse: true,    //Add this and your work is done
                controller: _scrollController,
                itemCount: messageList.length + 1,
                itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, index) {
                  return index == 0
                      ? Container()
                      : oneMessage(messageList[index - 1]);
                },
              ),
```

Now if you want to scroll to a particular location with some animation , this is a way not the best but since we dont have to scroll to a particular index of chat we can use this so

declare this in the stateful widget

```
final _controller = ScrollController();
```

Now on your listview.builder use this as

```
ListView.builder(
          controller: _controller,//add this controller
....),
```

Now on your onpressed or any function
use this

```
_animateToIndex(height) => _controller.animateTo(height, duration: Duration(seconds: 2), curve: Curves.fastOutSlowIn);
```

You need to supply the height you want to scroll to so this may have a disadvantage but then scrolling to top would require height= 0 ;

You can also follow this discussion
[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49153087/flutter-scrolling-to-a-widget-in-listview)

Comment: wrong, if you revers it so you need to scroll to the top

Comment: @Husamuldeen I edited my answer. Hope it could help