# How can i create two scrollable list in different direction that are synced with eachother in flutter

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart, mobile

I am unable to create two list like foodpanda app, I want two scrollable list that depends on eachother. but their direction should be different (for first list horizontal and for second vertical).
tell me how i can get such listview in flutter.

[image: dual lists scrollview]

Comment: You might want to look into [`ScrollController`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/ScrollController-class.html).

Comment: i am unable to find a way to create a list like that. please guide me. how can i achieve that task. i want two scrollable lists exactly show in above mentioned gif.

Comment: your gif seems to be broken

Comment: right click on it and open it in new tab , i dont know why its not showing here..  
https://gfycat.com/everlastingflimsyamurminnow.gif

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found a solution that helped me and will solve this same problem of yours. There are a few issues when dealing with scroll to index but the code snippet provided in the link is simple and well elaborated.

[Link to another Stackoverflow's query that resembles this problem.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49153087/flutter-scrolling-to-a-widget-in-listview/61709995#61709995)