# How to scroll down the height of the screen with a Button?

Tags: flutter, dart, scroll

I want to scroll down with the press of a Button, exactly the current screen height.

I already tried this [Flutter: Scrolling to a widget in ListView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49153087/flutter-scrolling-to-a-widget-in-listview) but it doesn't help much.

I am using a `SingleChildScrollView()` inside a `Scaffold`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a `ScrollController`.

```dart
final _controller = ScrollController();
```

Your callback.

```dart
void _onPressed() {
  // Get the height you want to scroll to. 
  final screenHeight = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;

  // If you don't want any animation, use this: 
  _controller.jumpTo(screenHeight);

  // Otherwise use this: 
  _controller.animateTo(screenHeight, curve: Curves.easeOut, duration: Duration(seconds: 1));
}
```

Your `SingleChildScrollView`:

```dart
SingleChildScrollView(
  controller: _controller,
  child: ...,
)
```

Comment: Try animateTo inside of setState

Comment: @rstrelba You don't need `setState` in any of the callbacks.