# How do I jump to a section in a list?

Tags: flutter, dart

How do I jump to a section in a list?

I created a list of drinks and below the list is the category of all the drink types, so I want to jump to a specific section on the list by the relevant button. I want to jump to the Gin section on the list when I press the Gin button and to the Whiskey section on the list when I press the whiskey button

The List implementation class

```
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/rendering.dart';
import 'package:fluttertoast/fluttertoast.dart';
import 'package:pass_data/cartitem.dart';
import 'package:pass_data/ginCocktails.dart';
import 'package:pass_data/main_drawer.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';
import 'cart.dart';
import 'dish_object.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ChangeNotifierProvider(
      create: (context) => cartitem(),
      child: MaterialApp(
        debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
        theme: ThemeData(
          backgroundColor: Colors.green,
        ),
        home: MyHomePage(title: "The Wing Republic"),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);
  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  List<Drinks> _dishes = List<Drinks>();
  List<Drinks> _cartList = List<Drinks>();

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _populateDishes();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text(widget.title),
          actions: <Widget>[
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 16.0, top: 8.0),
              child: GestureDetector(
                child: Stack(
                  alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Icon(
                      Icons.shopping_basket,
                      size: 35.0,
                    ),
                    if (_cartList.length > 0)
                      Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 2.0),
                        child: CircleAvatar(
                          radius: 8.0,
                          backgroundColor: Colors.red,
                          foregroundColor: Colors.white,
                          child: Text(
                            _cartList.length.toString(),
                            style: TextStyle(
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                              fontSize: 12.0,
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                  ],
                ),
                onTap: () {
                  if (_cartList.isNotEmpty)
                    Navigator.of(context).push(
                      MaterialPageRoute(
                        builder: (context) => Cart(_cartList),
                      ),
                    );

                  setState(() {
                    if (_cartList.isEmpty) {
                      Fluttertoast.showToast(
                          msg: "Cart Empty, Add items to Cart",
                          toastLength: Toast.LENGTH_LONG,
                          gravity: ToastGravity.BOTTOM,
                          timeInSecForIosWeb: 1,
                          backgroundColor: Colors.red,
                          textColor: Colors.white,
                          fontSize: 16.0);
                    }
                  });
                },
              ),
            ),
          ],
          backgroundColor: Colors.redAccent[100],
        ),
        drawer: MainDrawer(),
        body: Container(
            child: SingleChildScrollView(
                child: Align(
                    alignment: Alignment.center,
                    child: Column(mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min, children: <
                        Widget>[
                      Container(
                          width: 1000,
                          height: 500,
                          child: GridView.builder(
                              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(4.0),
                              gridDelegate:
                                  SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
                                      crossAxisCount: 2),
                              itemCount: _dishes.length,
                              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                                var item = _dishes[index];
                                return Card(
                                    elevation: 4.0,
                                    child: Stack(
                                      fit: StackFit.loose,
                                      alignment: Alignment.center,
                                      children: <Widget>[
                                        Column(
                                          mainAxisAlignment:
                                              MainAxisAlignment.center,
                                          children: <Widget>[
                                            Text(item.category),
                                            Text(
                                              item.brandName,
                                              textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                                              style: Theme.of(context)
                                                  .textTheme
                                                  .subhead,
                                            ),
                                            Text(
                                              "R" + item.price.toString(),
                                              textAlign: TextAlign.right,
                                            )
                                          ],
                                        ),
                                        Padding(
                                          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                                            right: 8.0,
                                            bottom: 8.0,
                                          ),
                                          child: Align(
                                            alignment: Alignment.bottomRight,
                                            child: GestureDetector(
                                              child: (!_cartList.contains(item))
                                                  ? Icon(
                                                      Icons.add_circle,
                                                      color: Colors.green,
                                                    )
                                                  : Icon(
                                                      Icons.remove_circle,
                                                      color: Colors.red,
                                                    ),
                                              onTap: () {
                                                setState(() {
                                                  if (!_cartList.contains(item))
                                                    _cartList.add(item);
                                                  else
                                                    _cartList.remove(item);
                                                });
                                              },
                                            ),
                                          ),
                                        ),
                                      ],
                                    ));
                              })),
                      Container(
                          margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 20.0),
                          height: 40.0,
                          width: 500,
                          child: ListView(
                              scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                              children: <Widget>[
                                RaisedButton(
                                  child: Text("GIN COCKTAILS"),
                                ),
                                SizedBox(
                                  width: 5,
                                ),
                                RaisedButton(
                                  child: Text("WHISK(e)Y COCKTAILS"),
                                ),
                                SizedBox(
                                  width: 5,
                                ),
                                RaisedButton(
                                  child: Text("COGNAC / BRANDY COCKTAILS"),
                                ),
                                SizedBox(
                                  width: 5,
                                ),
                                RaisedButton(
                                  child: Text("RUM COCKTAILS"),
                                ),
                                SizedBox(
                                  width: 5,
                                ),
                                RaisedButton(
                                  child: Text("TEQUILLA COCKTAILS"),
                                ),
                                SizedBox(
                                  width: 5,
                                ),
                                RaisedButton(
                                  child: Text("VODKA COCKTAILS"),
                                ),
                                SizedBox(
                                  width: 5,
                                ),
                                RaisedButton(
                                  child: Text("MOCKTAILS"),
                                ),
                                SizedBox(
                                  width: 5,
                                ),
                                RaisedButton(
                                  child: Text("SHOOTERS"),
                                ),
                                SizedBox(
                                  width: 5,
                                ),
                                RaisedButton(
                                  child: Text("BEERS & CIDERS"),
                                ),
                                SizedBox(
                                  width: 5,
                                ),
                                RaisedButton(
                                  child: Text("VODKA"),
                                ),
                                SizedBox(
                                  width: 5,
                                ),
                                RaisedButton(
                                  child: Text("LIQUEURS"),
                                ),
                                SizedBox(
                                  width: 5,
                                ),
                                RaisedButton(
                                  child: Text("WINE BY THE GLASS"),
                                ),
                                SizedBox(
                                  width: 5,
                                ),
                                RaisedButton(
                                  child: Text("WHITE WINE"),
                                ),
                                SizedBox(
                                  width: 5,
                                ),
                                RaisedButton(
                                  child: Text("RED WINE"),
                                ),
                                SizedBox(
                                  width: 5,
                                ),
                                RaisedButton(
                                  child: Text("MOSCATO | ROSE/BLUSH"),
                                ),
                                SizedBox(
                                  width: 5,
                                ),
                                RaisedButton(
                                  child: Text("BUBBLES"),
                                ),
                                SizedBox(
                                  width: 5,
                                ),
                                RaisedButton(
                                  child: Text("MCC"),
                                ),
                                SizedBox(
                                  width: 5,
                                ),
                                RaisedButton(
                                  child: Text("CHAMPAGNE"),
                                ),
                                SizedBox(
                                  width: 5,
                                ),
                                RaisedButton(
                                  child: Text("COGNAC"),
                                ),
                                SizedBox(
                                  width: 5,
                                ),
                                RaisedButton(
                                  child: Text("TEQUILLA"),
                                ),
                                SizedBox(
                                  width: 5,
                                ),
                                RaisedButton(
                                  child: Text("NON-ALCOHOLIC"),
                                ),
                              ]))
                    ])))));
  }

  void _populateDishes() {
    var list = <Drinks>[
      Drinks(
        category: 'Gin Cocktails',
        brandName: "Clover Club",
        price: 65,
      ),
      Drinks(
        category: 'Gin Cocktail',
        brandName: 'Tanqueray Sling',
        price: 99,
      ),
      Drinks(
        category: 'Gin Cocktail',
        brandName: 'French 75',
        price: 84,
      ),
      Drinks(
        category: 'Gin Cocktail',
        brandName: '1934 Cosmo',
        price: 85,
      ),
      Drinks(
        category: 'Gin Cocktail',
        brandName: "Sevilla Roseate",
        price: 80,
      ),
      Drinks(
        category: 'Gin Cocktail',
        brandName: 'TWR+ Sevilla Gimlet',
        price: 75,
      ),
      Drinks(
        category: 'WHISK(E)Y Cocktails',
        brandName: "Keep Walking Sling",
        price: 65,
      ),
      Drinks(
        category: 'WHISK(E)Y Cocktail',
        brandName: 'TWR+ Old Fashion',
        price: 85,
      ),
      Drinks(
        category: 'WHISK(E)Y Cocktail',
        brandName: 'Gold Standard',
        price: 120,
      ),
      Drinks(
        category: 'WHISK(E)Y Cocktail',
        brandName: 'Same as Jamie',
        price: 90,
      ),
      Drinks(
        category: 'WHISK(E)Y Cocktail',
        brandName: "Caskmates Sling",
        price: 95,
      ),
      Drinks(
        category: 'WHISK(E)Y Cocktail',
        brandName: 'The County Cork',
        price: 100,
      ),
      Drinks(
        category: 'WHISK(E)Y Cocktail',
        brandName: 'Johnie Walker Red ',
        price: 25,
      )
    ];
    setState(() {
      _dishes = list;
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: check `Scrollable.ensureVisible` static method

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49153087/flutter-scrolling-to-a-widget-in-listview

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Flutter: Scrolling to a widget in ListView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49153087/flutter-scrolling-to-a-widget-in-listview)

Comment: i am still on it