# How to scroll to a particular row in a GridView in flutter?

Tags: flutter

I'm trying to scroll to a particular row in a gridview. Currently i'm manually calculating how much to scroll and then animate to it using scrollController's animateTo function. Is there an easier or efficient way to do it ?

Comment: use `Scrollable.ensureVisible(...)`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49153087/flutter-scrolling-to-a-widget-in-listview