# Scroll to specific position in List

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to scroll to a specific position in a list. I tried using the scroll-to-index package but I can only see the possibility to scroll to a widget in a list but not the possibility to the EXACT position on the widget in the list. Does anyone have a idea how to do it?
Thanks for help!

Comment: Check this answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49153087/flutter-scrolling-to-a-widget-in-listview

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Flutter: Scrolling to a widget in ListView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49153087/flutter-scrolling-to-a-widget-in-listview)