# Flutter mobile anchor menu links

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I have set of tags in top of the page like '#Java, #C++, #PHP' and list of widgets related to those tags, When I click on the tag, I need to scroll down and focus on related widget(Ex: if you click on #java tag it should automatically scroll to java widget) in the same page. Can anyone tell me how to do it on flutter?

Comment: Have a look at this [Medium](https://medium.com/flutter-community/flutter-for-single-page-scrollable-websites-with-navigator-2-0-part-1-introduction-c219b471bbec) article

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Flutter: Scrolling to a widget in ListView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49153087/flutter-scrolling-to-a-widget-in-listview)

Comment: Thanks Prince and Mostafa Soliman.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.