# How to skip an index in an ListView Flutter

Tags: flutter, listview

I'm trying to use a simple **ListView** in Flutter. The problem is that i want to use **two indices** (index) of my list **for one card**.

So if when the ListView is expanding it should always use two indices. The first Card has access to data from index 1 and 2, the second card from 3 and 4 and so on.

If anyone knows how to build something like this I'd appreciate :)

Comment: Can you include your code-snippet and a UI that you are you trying to archive ?

Comment: You might want to do something like this https://stackoverflow.com/a/58435822/9138914

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see 2 ways to handle that situation...

### First

You can generate other list where each element will contain 2 elements of the original list.

### Second

Use isOdd or isEven to ignore some indexes.

```
ListView.builder(
  itemCount: myList.length
  itemBuilder: (_, index) {
    if(index.isEven){
       return MyCustomTile(
         first: myList[index]
         second: index + 1 == myList.length ? null : myList[index+1]
       );
    }
    return Container();
  }
)
```

Attention to not get an index out of the bounds of your list

Comment: Thank you very much. I just found out too. New day new thoughts ^^.

Answer (score 2):

Also possible is to do this:

```dart
SizedBox.shrink();
```

Saving code lines :)

Comment: While it’s acceptable to provide code-only answers, it’s often more useful for the community if you can also provide an explanation of the code and help people understand why it addresses the problem. That often reduces the amount of follow-up questions, and can really help new developers understand the underlying concepts.

Answer (score 1):

That's how I handled it, in case someone could use it in the future:

```
ListView.builder(
              scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
              itemCount: itemList.length,
              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                if (index % 2 == 0 && index < itemList.length) {
                  return Column(
                    children: [
                      ListElementWidget(data: itemList[index]),
                      (index + 1 < itemList.length)
                          ? Padding(
                              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 8.0),
                              child: ListElementWidget(
                                  data: itemList[index + 1]),
                            )
                          : const SizedBox(
                              width: 0,
                            ),
                    ],
                  );
                } else {
                  return const SizedBox(width: 0);
                }
              },
            ),
          ),
```

There is definitely a nicer way to design non-existent widgets other than with sizedbox size 0. But I'm fairly new to flutter and it works.