# How to scroll specific item in Singlechildscrollview?

Tags: flutter, dart, listview, singlechildscrollview

I have a SingleChildScrollView, its scrollDirection is set to Vertical with number children widgets placed inside a ListView.bulder Widget. I want to programmatically scroll to the middle widget in the ListView and when the middle widget is reached(waits 2 seconds).

Scroll specific item in SigleChildScrollView.

Comment: `SingleChildScrollView` only has one child. You want to scroll to specific item in `ListView`. And why do you have `ListView` inside `SingleChildScrollView`?

Comment: Because My design has some widgets with ListView in SingleChildScrollView .

Comment: this seems like a duplicate of this question.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49153087/flutter-scrolling-to-a-widget-in-listview