# Create a Gesture Detector that redirect to a certain widget Flutter

Tags: flutter

I wanted to create a specific section for my mobile app (Called POW section), and I want to also create a `floatingButton` that will redirect user to `POW section` when `tapped`.

The section is still in the same page as the floating button. So if user scroll too much and cover the pow section this button will appear and when it tapped the screen will be scrolled until the pow Section is shown again.

How to achieve this ? Thanks before.

Comment: Do update your question with, what do you mean by redirect? Is a separate route or is it on the same route and you want to bring the `POW Section` into view.

Comment: I already update my question, please review it again

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Flutter: Scrolling to a widget in ListView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49153087/flutter-scrolling-to-a-widget-in-listview)