# How does flutter scroll to an item position in the listview according to its index?

Tags: android, flutter, flutter-dependencies

How does flutter scroll to an item position in the listview according to its index?

A list scrolls to a specific item, but the height of the item may be uncertain

for example: scroll to the 22nd ListTile in the list

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49153087/flutter-scrolling-to-a-widget-in-listview. Look at `ScrollablePositionedList`.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, Flutter doesn't have `controller.jumpToIndex(index);`

you can achieve this by adding a third-party library which is called [**scrollable_positioned_list**](https://pub.dev/packages/scrollable_positioned_list).

It is exactly like ListView but you can use `controller.jumpToIndex(index);`

For Example:

Init controller:

```
final ItemScrollController itemScrollController = ItemScrollController();
```

Add widget:

```
 ScrollablePositionedList.builder(
  itemCount: 500,
  itemBuilder: (context, index) => Text('Item $index'),
  itemScrollController: itemScrollController,
  scrollOffsetController: scrollOffsetController,
  itemPositionsListener: itemPositionsListener,
  scrollOffsetListener: scrollOffsetListener,
);
```

Call `scrollTo` method:

```
itemScrollController.scrollTo(
index: 150,
duration: Duration(seconds: 2),
curve: Curves.easeInOutCubic);
```

**Happy Coding :)**